# The input field should occupy all the space provided

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a code of this type:

```
<View style={test.textInputWrapp}>
  <SvgXml height={30} width={30} style={styles.iconLeftBottom} xml={storage.add_circle_outline_28} />
  <TextInput multiline={true} placeholder="Введите текст..." style={test.textInput} />
  <SvgXml height={30} width={30} style={styles.iconLeftBottom} xml={storage.smile_outline_28} />
  <SvgXml height={30} width={30} style={styles.iconLeftBottom} xml={storage.voice_outline_28} />

  textInputWrapp: {
    paddingTop: 5,
    height: 50,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  textInput: {
    width: 'auto',
    height: 35,
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#E1E3E6',
  },
  iconLeftBottom: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginTop: 4,
  },
</View>
```

I need to make an adaptive input field so that it maximally fills the free space depending on the orientation of the device

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dimensions` from `react-native` to get width and height of device.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;


const App = () => {

   return (
  
        <TextInput multiline={true} placeholder="Введите текст..." style={{ width: WIDTH }} />
    
  )
}
```

Comment: Bad answer. Because after change orientation input will be very big or very small. He must occupy all the FREE space